# How to call one function inside another function in same controller in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, arrays, function, laravel-5

GetEstimateController.php

```
class GetEstimationController extends Controller
{
    public function fill_dropbox(){
        $data = ProcedureTreat::get(['pro_name']);  
        $data1 = HospitalPackage::get(['address']);  
        // return $this->get_estimate();
        // dd($data);
        return View::make('get_quote')->with('address',$data1)->with('procedureName',$data);
    }
    public function get_estimate($name,$address){
        $data = HospitalPackage::where(['pro' => 'name', 'address' => 'address'])->get();
        $Dropbox_fill = $this->fill_dropbox();
        // dd($Dropbox_fill);
        return View::make('get_quote')->with('HospitalPack',$data);
    }
}
```

Routes.php

```
Route::get('/',[
    'uses' => 'GetEstimationController@fill_dropbox',
    'as' => 'fill.dropbox'
]);
Route::any('/find/{name}/{address}',[
    'uses' => 'GetEstimationController@get_estimate',
    'as' => 'get.estimate'
]);
```

get_quote.blade.php

```
@if(isset($procedureName))
       @foreach($procedureName as $key => $data)
         <option value="{{$data->pro_name}}">{{$data->pro_name}}</option>
       @endforeach                               
    @endif
    @if(isset($address))
      @foreach($address as $key => $add)
        <option value="{{$add->address}}">{{$add->address}}</option>
      @endforeach
    @endif
```

I want to call `fill_dropbox` funtion inside `get_estimate` function and want to send data to `get_quote.blade.php` again.

Using `$Dropbox_fill = $this->fill_dropbox();` I'm getting data

```
View {#155 ▼
  #factory: Factory {#141 ▶}
  #engine: CompilerEngine {#148 ▶}
  #view: "get_quote"
  #data: array:2 [▼
    "address" => Collection {#2507 ▼
      #items: array:1382 [▼
        0 => HospitalPackage {#2508 …24}
        1 => HospitalPackage {#2509 …24}
        2 => HospitalPackage {#2510 …24}
        3 => HospitalPackage {#2511 …24}
      }
    "procedureName" => Collection {#1124 ▶}
  ]
  #path: "C:\wamp\www\IIMTC\bmmt_new\resources\views/get_quote.blade.php"
}
```

so how can I access it in `get_quote.blade.php` with previous `foreach` .

Comment: return View::make('get_quote')->with('data',['HospitalPack' => $data,'Dropbox_fill' => $Dropbox_fill]);

Comment: try my answer @Giridhari Lal

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to send data to a view. One of them is as below,

```
return View::make('get_quote', ['HospitalPack' => $data,'Dropbox_fill' => $Dropbox_fill]);
```

and your view file name should be get_quote.blade.php

Comment: how will I fetch `Dropbox_fill` array element in `get_quote` page?

Comment: @Kuru has posted you in his answer on how to access this variable in your view. Exactly you can use the same code

Comment: same error is showing using this code. `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\wamp\www\IIMTC\bmmt_new\resources\views\get_quote.blade.p‌​hp)` @manian

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
public function get_estimate($name,$address){
        $HospitalPack= HospitalPackage::where(['pro' => 'name', 'address' => 'address'])->get();
        $Dropbox_fill = $this->fill_dropbox();
        // dd($Dropbox_fill);
        return View::make('get_quote',compact('HospitalPack','Dropbox_fill'));
    }
```

then in view, you can access like this

```
@if(isset($HospitalPack))
       @foreach($HospitalPackas as $key => $data)
         #your data
       @endforeach                               
    @endif
@if(isset($Dropbox_fill ))
           @foreach($Dropbox_fill as $key => $data)
             #your data
           @endforeach                               
        @endif
```

Comment: there is a space next to 'Dropbox_fill' in your controller code. Can you please correct this one

Comment: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\wamp\www\IIMTC\bmmt_new\resources\views\get_quote.blade.php)` this error is showing.

Comment: did you try the edited answer, because the answer i publish has the error. Can you try `{{dd($HospitalPack)}}` in your view and display the output?

Comment: Showing undefined Variable :

Comment: for `$Dropbox_fill` also you get the same.... try `dd` command in you controller before pass it to the view to make sure you are getting the data

Comment: I think no need to show again in `get_quote.blade.php` page. It has auto filled with previous code.

Comment: I think if I'm calling `fill_dropbox` function in `get_estimate` function then it is returning before executing this statement `return View::make('get_quote', ['HospitalPack' => $HospitalPack,'Dropbox_fill' => $Dropbox_fill]);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144462/discussion-between-kuru-and-giridhari-lal).

Answer (score 0):

Pass the data like this

```
return View::make('get_quote')->with('data',['HospitalPack' => $data,'Dropbox_fill' => $Dropbox_fill]);
```

In view access data like this

```
    $data['HospitalPack'];  
    $data['Dropbox_fill'];
```

OR USE COMPACT()

```
 return View::make('get_quote',compact('HospitalPack','Dropbox_fill');
```

In view access like this

```
   $HospitalPack
```