# error: Showing undefined variable .in laravel 5.2 while passing two array to View

Tags: php, arrays, database, eloquent, laravel-5

[image]GetEstimateController.php

```
public function fill_dropbox(){
        $data = ProcedureTreat::get(['pro_name']);  
        $data1 = HospitalPackage::get(['address']);  
        // return $this->get_estimate();
        // dd($data);
        return View::make('get_quote')->with('address',$data1)->with('procedureName',$data);
    }
    public function get_estimate($name,$addr){
        // dd($name);
        $HospitalPack = HospitalPackage::where(['pro' => $name, 'address' => $addr])->orderBy('treat_price', 'desc')->get()->first();
        $Dropbox_fill = $this->fill_dropbox();
        // dd($HospitalPack);
        return View::make('get_quote')->with(compact('Dropbox_fill','HospitalPack'));
    }
```

if I'm using

```
return View::make('get_quote')->with(compact('Dropbox_fill','HospitalPack'));
```

this line it is showing error while using

```
return View::make('get_quote')->with(compact('HospitalPack'));
```

this code it is not showing error.

Comment: Well, you are getting undefined variable, I suppose you performed the dd($HospitalPack);, but did you perform it on $Dropbox_fill as well? try dd($Dropbox_fill); to see if it returns anything.

Comment: both are showing some data but while I'm trying to access at view page it is showing error.

Comment: how do you access `Dropbox_fill` from your view?

Comment: i just noticed, when you do $this->fill_dropbox(), the fill_dropbox() method has a return View in itself, so you're probably not even hitting this line return View::make('get_quote')->with(compact('Dropbox_fill','HospitalPack')); at all, in exactly which line did you get the error?

Comment: `{{dd($Dropbox_fill)}}` doing this to check

Comment: `return View::make('get_quote')->with(compact('Dropbox_fill','Hospit‌​alPack'));` I'm getting error here. but I also thought as same but `$Dropbox_fill` data is showing in view without accessing this variable.

Comment: If i'm removing `return View::make('get_quote')->with(compact('Dropbox_fill','Hospit‌​alPack'));` this line then it is not showing means this line is hitting but I think it's conflict with another function may be but I'm not getting exact problem

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44024282/how-to-call-one-function-inside-another-function-in-same-controller-in-laravel-5) You can see here whole code.

Comment: Can you post your error here as well? an image of it or the text?

Comment: `ErrorException in df49bba7919d36c0947f3180277cc0ad1c31c0d3.php line 59: Undefined variable: Dropbox_fill (View: C:\wamp\www\IIMTC\bmmt_new\resources\views\get_quote.blade.php)`

Comment: Have you tried this? return View::make('get_quote',compact('HospitalPack','Dropbox_fill'));

Comment: Yes both giving same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144473/discussion-between-omar-tarek-and-giridhari-lal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was indeed in the return statement inside the fill_dropbox() method, so if you did it like this:

```
public function get_estimate($name,$addr){

$HospitalPack = HospitalPackage::where(['pro' => $name, 'address' => $addr])->orderBy('treat_price', 'desc')->get()->first();

$data = ProcedureTreat::get(['pro_name']);

$data1 = HospitalPackage::get(['address']);

return View::make('get_quote')->with(compact('data', 'HospitalPack', 'data1'));
}
```

Everything should be working now :)